# Kendo UI grid dropdown and angular

Tags: angularjs, binding, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I try to setup custom dropdown in Kendo UI.

I have a reference to my issue.

http://dojo.telerik.com/aFIZa/13

My issue is that I do not know how I can setup the selected text in the template attribute? I want to show the text field but save the id as a value. **And I do not want to use external datasource. I would like it as inline in the json.**

The code is below:

```
 $scope.mainGridOptions = {
    dataSource: $scope.dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [

      { field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "180px", 
       editor: function(container, options) {
    var editor = $('<input kendo-drop-down-list required k-data-text-field="\'cat\'" k-data-value-field="\'id\'" k-data-source="{data:[{id: 1, cat: \'test\'}, {id: 2, cat: \'test2\'}]}" data-bind="value:Category"/>')
    .appendTo(container);

    $compile(editor)($scope);
    editor.css("visibility", "visible");
       }

         , template:"selected text in the combo "
      }
  ], editable: true


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, this was a tough one, but I think I could achieve what you want, or at least I got closer:

```
$scope.mainGridOptions = 
{
    dataSource: $scope.dataSource,
    pageable: true,
    height: 550,
    toolbar: ["create"],
    columns: [
    { 
        field: "Category", title: "Category", width: "180px", 
        editor: function(container, options) 
        {
            // #1
            var editor = $('<input kendo-drop-down-list required k-data-text-field="\'cat\'" k-data-value-field="\'id\'" k-data-source="{data:[{id: 1, cat: \'test\'}, {id: 2, cat: \'test2\'}]}" data-bind="value:Category,events:{ change: onChange }"/>')
            .appendTo(container);

            $compile(editor)($scope);
            editor.css("visibility", "visible");
        }, 

        // #2
        template:kendo.template($("#column-template").html())
    }], 
    editable: true,

    // #3
    edit: function(e) 
    {
        var ko = kendo.observable(
        {
            onChange: function(e) 
            {
                var el = $(e.sender.element);
                var ddl = el.data("kendoDropDownList");
                var ds = $scope.dataSource.getByUid(el.closest("tr").data("uid"));

                ds.OptionText = ddl.text();
            },
        });

        var widget = $(e.container).find("input");
        kendo.bind(widget, ko);
    }
}});
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/aFIZa/14).

In the code you can notice 3 changes:

1. `data-bind="value:Category,events:{ change: onChange }"` Look that I have added an `events` object in the bind, which I declare `onChange` as the [`change`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change) event handler. We'll talk about this in the 3rd item below;
2. For a complex template(with javascript code and logic) I created a script content and rendered it at the `template` property. The template is this:

   ```
   <script id="column-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
       # if (data.hasOwnProperty('OptionText')) { #
       #: OptionText #
       # } else { #
       #: "selected text in the combo" #
       # } #
   </script>
   ```

   In the template I simply check for the property `OptionText` in the model(dataSource's current item) and: if it exists, use it; else, use the default text. We'll talk about `OptionText` in the 3rd item, below;
3. Now, here I have added an `edit` event to the grid. In that event I created an [`observable`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/observableobject) object, where I define the `onChange` function handler. In that function I seek for the current dataSource(`ds`) and I add text of the selected item in the dropdownlist in it, as the property `OptionText`, which I use in the template above explained.

I hope this explains how it works(in fact I hate working with those binders and observables, but sometimes they are needed).

Good luck.

Comment: Wow. It's a nice answer. But am I alone to have this issue? I thought there was something easier. Generally, I show the text from the grid datasource. Then I select a value in the combo. The combo has id and text. I show the text selected in the dropdown and save the id as value. How other people are delaing with this? Am I complicating too much the scenario of Grid with dropdown? Also how can I show the values corresponding in the grid before editing it? Thanks for your very detailed and clear answer!

Comment: @ameilland I'm afraid no, you're not alone on this. I have search more than 30 posts to get on this answer, many of them posted by confused users. Things in kendo sometimes get much more complicated than it needs, thats why I said I hate using binders and observables. On thing I think could make things easier is to change the value directly in the dataSource when you change the dropdown, then refresh the grid, instead of using template. Other point is to avoid inline edits, I mean, like open a popup with the dropdown or something like that.

Comment: Ok I investigated a little. And it seems this example seems more simple if you are interested. http://jsbin.com/obufum/1/edit?html,js,output It uses template: "#=getCategoryName(CategoryID)#"

Comment: @ameilland the example is nice, you can use it, but it will need a few adjusts, but its ok and simpler, actually.

Comment: In the example, it is using getCategoryName function and the datasource categories. Categories is a datasource object not inline. Do you know how can I access to the datasource if it's inline like in my first example? If I cannot I will create a map with keys and datasources. And I will set them with the key. The reason why I want a datasource inline is that the setup of my table is sent from the server as json.

Comment: @ameilland sorry, I don't get what you meant by *"inline dataSource"*, there are two type: with data generated in the code; or by async request. Once loaded, you can always get the dataSource, e.g. `$("#example kendo-grid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource`.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown can you please help out me too [Drop down option disable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46589379/kendo-grid-inline-edit-with-drop-down-option-disabled)